# JNA: Invalid memory access when calling COM method of dll via jdk-11 64-bit

Tags: java, com, jna

I am using JNA (5.9.0) to access a COM library gbda_aut.dll for connecting to OPC server. The problem occurs when I use 64-bit version of dll.

I have created classes by a code generator [TlbCodeGenerator](https://github.com/matthiasblaesing/TlbCodeGenerator). As a result I have an interface OPCItems with the following method:

```
/**
 * Adds an OPCItem object to the collection
 *
 * <p>id(0x6002000b)</p>
 * <p>vtableId(18)</p>
 * @param ItemID [in] {@code String}
 * @param ClientHandle [in] {@code Integer}
 */
@ComMethod(name = "AddItem", dispId = 0x6002000b)
OPCItem AddItem(String ItemID, int ClientHandle);
```

The same method of this dll in OLE/COM Object Viewer:

```
[id(0x6002000b), helpstring("Adds an OPCItem object to the collection")]
HRESULT AddItem(
                [in] BSTR ItemID, 
                [in] long ClientHandle, 
                [out, retval] OPCItem** ppItem);
```

My test code:

```
Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
OPCServer opcServer = factory.createObject(OPCServer.class);
opcServer.Connect("Matrikon.OPC.Simulation", null);
OPCGroups opcGroups = opcServer.getOPCGroups();
OPCGroup opcGroup = opcGroups.Add("TestGroup");
OPCItems opcItems = opcGroup.getOPCItems();
OPCItem opcItem = opcItems.AddItem("TestGroup.DoubleTag", 1); // invalid memory access via JDK 11 x64 + Windows 10
System.out.println(opcItem.getValue()); // works with Windows before 10 or jdk 8
opcServer.Disconnect();
```

Connection is OK, other methods work fine. The error occurs within a method AddItem with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:306)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMInvoker._invokeNativeObject(COMInvoker.java:48)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.Dispatch.Invoke(Dispatch.java:145)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.ProxyObject.oleMethod(ProxyObject.java:726)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.ProxyObject.invokeMethod(ProxyObject.java:450)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.ProxyObject.invoke(ProxyObject.java:256)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.AddItem(Unknown Source)
    at test.OpcTest.main(OpcTest.java:20)
```

I tested it with different versions of JDK and Windows and I got the following results:

|  | Win 7 | Win 2008 Server | Win 10 | Win 2012 Server |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Java 8 x32 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Java 8 x64 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Java 11 x32 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Java 11 x64 | OK | OK | exception | exception |
| Java 16 x64 | OK | OK | exception | exception |

I guess the error occurs inside the native dll code, but I am not clear why everything works fine with older versions of Java or Windows. I do not have access to the dll code and I cannot change it.

Is it possible to call the method correctly so that the error does not occur in the JDK 11 64bit + Windows 10/2012?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Win10/2012 don't change so much things that would explain why it fails with Java 11+ and/or x64 (or maybe Java itself but it seems doubtful too). It definitely needs a look at the code behind `AddItem`

Comment: It is possible, that GC kills the objects to early. Could you please add a java.lang.ref.Reference#reachabilityFence (needs JDK 9+) call for all the COM objects after the #disconnect call? If that works, we can discuss option how you can work around this yourself and how it can be fixed in JNA.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are mapping has three arguments:

```
HRESULT AddItem(
                [in] BSTR ItemID, 
                [in] long ClientHandle, 
                [out, retval] OPCItem** ppItem);
```

But your implementation only has two:

```java
OPCItem AddItem(String ItemID, int ClientHandle);
```

Somewhere in your codebase is an implementation that maps your two-arg Java method to the three-arg native function:

- Make sure `ppItem` in that function is a `PointerByReference` type
- Make sure the return `OPCItem` object is instantiated from `ppItem.getValue()`

Ensure you are using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the dll appropriately.  It's possible that the `long` parameter type can be 32-bit or 64-bit.  While on Windows, `LONG` is always 32-bit, the lowercase `long` may indicate a variable width type in your dll, and you might try `NativeLong` for the type of `ClientHandle` in the mapping.

Comment: The question is targeted at the COM support in the "c.s.j.platform.win32.COM.util" package. That runs through the IDispatch#Invoke method (basicly reflection for COM). The signature shown in the question is for an interface, but we need the Dispinterface.  If you have Oleview, you can compare the signature of the nodeName method on the IXMLDOMNode interface and the IXMLDOMNode Dispinterface. You can then see, that the return value of the Dispinterface method becomes the out parameter of the Interface.